# Leaked window com.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView

Tags: android

I've dont know where's the error is...
I've try to debug it but error keeps coming and coming.

```
 public class ActivityOwner extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private Button btnLogin;
        private EditText username, password;
        private TextView tvLinkToRegister;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); //---JSON parser class

        //---Testing on android device:
        private static final String OWNER_LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.2.5/idot/owner_login.php";

        //---Testing on Emulator:
        //private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:1234/idot/register.php";
        //---Testing from a real server:
        //Private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://domain name/sub folder/register.php";

        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_owner);

            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOwnerUsername);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOwnerPassword);

            tvLinkToRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);
            btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOwnerLogin);

            tvLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent registrationForm = new Intent(ActivityOwner.this, ActivityOwnerRegister.class);
                    startActivity(registrationForm);
                }
            });

            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        }

        class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityOwner.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                String stringUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String stringPassword = password.getText().toString();
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("owner_username", stringUsername));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("owner_password", stringPassword));

                    Log.d("request!", "starting");
                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(OWNER_LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                        // save user data
                        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityOwner.this);
                        Editor edit = sp.edit();
                        edit.putString("owner_username", stringUsername);
                        edit.commit();

                        Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOwner.this, ActivityOwnerSuccessLogin.class);
                        //progressDialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(i);

                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                    } else {
                        Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (file_url != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityOwner.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }
```

-LOGCAT-------

```
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609): Activity ph.idot.sp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4101cf78 that was originally added here
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ph.idot.sp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4101cf78 that was originally added here
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:349)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:285)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at ph.idot.owner.ActivityOwner$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(ActivityOwner.java:88)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at ph.idot.owner.ActivityOwner.onClick(ActivityOwner.java:76)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-14 14:37:14.460: E/WindowManager(11609):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's the problem here? Help me please.

Comment: uncomment your progressDiaolog.dismiss() in doInBackground and try once...

Comment: Already tried it but it just the same..

Answer (score 3):

Leak window Error comes usually when view is unable to find the context with which it was Started or initialized.

Dismiss the progress dialog first before starting new activity.
As when your new activity starts when your previous activity dialog doesn't find the context for same.
So write your dialog dismiss code in  onpause method or in on destroy method .

And here You are starting the activity in doinbackground method and finishing the dialog in postexecute which is giving rise to leak window error.

try this :

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
             if(success==1){     
                      if (progressDialog != null) {
                          if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                 progressDialog.dismiss();
                          }
                            //Start your activity here . . . .  

                          }
                     }
                if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityOwner.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are to finish the activity before closing the dialog..
Try this.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   if (progressDialog != null) {
      if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
          progressDialog.dismiss();
      }
   }
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are starting new intent in doInBackground 
before you start new activity you need to disniss ProgressDialog

i prefer this code for dismiss ProgressDialog. pd is ProgressDialog in below code

```
    @Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing()){
        pd.dismiss();
    }
    super.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: where should i put this?

Comment: activity class (in your case put in ActivityOwner)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ActivityOwner extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private EditText username, password;
    private TextView tvLinkToRegister;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); //---JSON parser class

    //---Testing on android device:
    private static final String OWNER_LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.2.5/idot/owner_login.php";

    //---Testing on Emulator:
    //private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:1234/idot/register.php";
    //---Testing from a real server:
    //Private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://domain name/sub folder/register.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_owner);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOwnerUsername);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOwnerPassword);

        tvLinkToRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOwnerLogin);

        tvLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent registrationForm = new Intent(ActivityOwner.this, ActivityOwnerRegister.class);
                startActivity(registrationForm);
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new AttemptLogin().execute();
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     int success;
            String stringUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String stringPassword = password.getText().toString();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityOwner.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("owner_username", stringUsername));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("owner_password", stringPassword));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(OWNER_LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityOwner.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    // save user data
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityOwner.this);
                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("owner_username", stringUsername);
                    edit.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOwner.this, ActivityOwnerSuccessLogin.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();


            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Try my updated answer. I can't test it now, but give it a try.